# How can I create a list of dataframe - that are in memory- then export all as csv files?

Tags: r

I intend to mount a list of dataframe then use a loop structure to write each in a .csv file. Something like that:

```
for (i in myDataFramelist) 
  write.csv( ...)
```

Comment: Use `lapply`, which is designed for iterating over a list. If you need a multivariate version that iterates in parallel (say over your list and a vector of names), see `?Map`. [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) provides versions of these functions, if you like.

Comment: how can I use write.csv function nested with lapply?

Comment: Since you'll usually need a vector of names, too, it usually looks like `Map(function(df, filename) write.csv(df, filename), myDataFrameList, filenames)`. In this case you don't even really need the anonymous function, so you could reduce it to `Map(write.csv, myDataFrameList, filenames)`

Comment: Map sounds a good option! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it might not be the best way of doing it, I guess this example can make you understand a way through:

```
mat1<- matrix(1:9,3,3)
mat2<- matrix(1:16,4,4)
mylist <- list(mat1,mat2)

for( i in 1:length(mylist)){
  name<- paste0("matrix",i) ## Write the name you want
  write.csv(mylist[[i]], name) # Add the location where you want to store the file if so
}
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working with a list and mention `dplyr`, `purrr`'s `walk` functions are well suited. Unlike `map`, `walk` expects to apply a function to each element of a list without returning or printing to the console, so it's a good choice for saving files. `iwalk` takes both the list elements and the list elements' names, which is useful for creating file names. Here are a few ways to do it. For dummy data, I split the `mpg` data frame and took the first 3 elements.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_list <- mpg %>% split(.$manufacturer) %>% `[`(1:3)

# makes files mpg_audi.csv, etc
iwalk(df_list, function(df, name) {
  write_csv(df, sprintf("mpg_%s.csv", name))
})
```

`purrr` functions let you use dot notation as a shorthand—for something more complex than this, I'd prefer writing out the function as above, just to be clear about what's going on, but in this case `.x` is shorthand for each data frame and `.y` is shorthand for each data frame's name.

```r
# makes files mpg_audi_dot_notation.csv, etc
iwalk(df_list, ~write_csv(.x, sprintf("mpg_%s_dot_notation.csv", .y)))
```

If your list doesn't have names, you can instead use `walk2`, which takes two arguments, and use the location in the list as the second argument.

```r
names(df_list) <- NULL

# makes files mpg_1.csv, etc
walk2(df_list, 1:length(df_list), ~write_csv(.x, sprintf("mpg_%s.csv", .y)))
```

Created on 2018-06-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

R is a highly vectorized language, so you usually don't need to use `for` loops :

```
lapply(Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)), ls()), 
       function(x) write.csv(get(x), paste0(x, ".csv")))
```

Explanation:

- You use `lapply` as you're going to apply a function to a list
- `ls` gives all objects in envirnoment
- `is.data.frame` will return TRUE if the object is a data.frame
- `Filter` will select wich are TRUE
- You already know what `write.csv` does, you pass `get(x)` as the object to be saved, and make a name with the object's name

Comment: It's better to use [a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/4497050) like the OP already has than `get`.

Comment: @alistaire please help me learn a bit more about this... From the title ("how can I create a list of data frames in memory) I understand that the OP doesn't really have a list, and therefore I used the `get` and `ls` to build it. But provided that there's such a list, why is it better to use the list than to making it with `get`? is it time only?. Thanks, I learn a lot from you guys!

Comment: In that case the question isn't that important, but Gregor's answer is excellent and gets to your question. To summarize, there are 2 main benefits: 1. It scales better, so you end up with one list instead of thousands of data frames in your global environment, and can name them how you like without worrying about how to access them. 2. R has lots of excellent ways to iterate over and manipulate lists. There are great tools for coercing a list of data frames to a single one, too, e.g. `dplyr::bind_rows` and `data.table::rbindlist`.